# React Native module with Swift UIView and .xib file

Tags: swift, react-native, uiview, xib, react-native-modules

I am building a custom RN module where I want to expose Swift UIViews from my library to others to use in their RN app. I have a basic example working with a Swift UIView class showing up in my RN module example app:

```
@objc(TestViewManager)
class TestViewManager : RCTViewManager {
    
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func view() -> UIView! {
    //let myCustomView: TestView = UIView.fromNib()
    return TestView()
  }
}
```

When I try to load TestView with nib (using the myCustomView  fromNib() init) the RN app builds and runs but then crashes. This is my UIView extension:

```
extension UIView {
    class func fromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return Bundle(for: T.self).loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! T
    }
}
```

TestView.swift - my `.xib` file is named TestView.xib and has File Owner set to TestView.swift:

```
public class TestView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Are .xib files "allowed" in RN modules? I couldn't find any docs on this. Does anyone have any suggestions or know if this is possible?

Comment: Did you find any solution, brother?

Answer (score 0):

you need put xib to bundle and load xib with bundle

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.